# Rename multiple files in windows using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have multiple files named as

```
OBBN_0810_EMPTY.txt
OBBN_0810_FULL.txt
OBBN_0810_SMALL.txt
OBBN_0810_BIG.txt
OBBN_0810_INK.txt
```

I want to rename them like

```
OBHL_8554_COLL.txt
OBHL_8554_FULL.txt
OBHL_8554_SMALL.txt
OBHL_8554_BIG.txt
OBHL_8554_INK.txt
```

How do I do that in windows cmd.

For a single file its easy we can just rename it using

`ren 'OBBN_0810_INK.txt' 'OBHL_8554_INK.txt'`

*I just want to replace a substring from another string not the complete renaming*

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the rules of the replacement? Especially explain why _EMPTY gets renamed to _COLL. What have you tried?

Comment: In this particular case we just need to modify the string by replacing the numerical values and the preceding two letters before the numbers
Like in the example replacing BN_0810 with HL_8554.
I have designed a python script which works fine, just need to do with CMD. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/indexsrv/ms-dos-and-windows-wildcard-characters). It works quite intuitively. You can do it in 2 steps:

```
ren OBBN_0810_*.txt OBHL_8554_*.txt
ren *_EMPTY.txt *_COLL.txt
```